# New Rails installation - no such file to load -- phusion_passenger/alalytics_logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger, rvm

I just installed Ruby on Rails on my server and keep getting the following error when I view the  page.

```
Error Message:
     No such file to load -- phusion_pasenger/analytics_logger
```

Current Installation:

- Ubuntu 10.04 64
- Apache 2
- RVM 1.5.2
- Ruby 1.8.7 EE
- Rails 3.0.5
- Passenger 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongus Pong's answer came in while I was typing the same thing about permissions.

Check into the PassengerUser and PassengerUserSwitching directives to setup the appropriate users and permissions. http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerUserSwitching

More specific info here regarding how these directives operate: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#user_switching

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a permissions problem. Does the user have access to the phusion_pasenger folder?