# no such file to load -- phusion_passenger/analytics_logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Rails installation - no such file to load — phusion_passenger/alalytics_logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487522/new-rails-installation-no-such-file-to-load-phusion-passenger-alalytics-log)

I am receiving the following error after deploying our Rails application using Apache + Passenger.

> Ruby (Rack) application could not be
>   started
>
> Error message: no such file to load --
>   phusion_passenger/analytics_logger

Can anyone please put some light what can be causing this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more descriptive - let us know at least passenger gem version.  Did you tried any other version of passenger?

Comment: Has this issue been resolved? I am also getting the same error. I am using Phusion Passenger for Nginx `passenger 3.0.12`

Comment: This seems to be happening with both Apache and Nginx.

Comment: This is a permissions issue, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487522/new-rails-installation-no-such-file-to-load-phusion-passenger-alalytics-log